# Which sentence is correct grammar

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

A little background info, one of my favorite bands is doing a world tour next year. I live on the East Coast and all their concerts on the East Coast are in July, August and September. I am going to be in Greece those three months. So, if I was to write a sentence where I am disappointed about that, how would it go?

1. Of course,  all the concerts on the East Coast had to be on the same dates as my trip to Greece

Or

2. All the concerts on the East Coast are on the same dates as my trip to Greece.

Or

3. All the concerts on the East Coast are happening while I am traveling to Greece.

............................

If you have a completely different way to word it, I am all ears :)

Comment: These are all correct. Seems this is not a grammar question, but rather you are having difficulty expressing what you mean.  Perhaps start the sentences with "Unfortunately, ..."

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of these three sentences, however, as it is unlikely that it will take you three months to travel to Greece, I think that the third would be better if you said:

> All the concerts on the East Coast are happening while I am **holidaying 
>   in** Greece.

Or possibly:

> All the concerts on the East Coast will be happening while I am **holidaying 
>   in** Greece.

This, of course, assumes that you will be holidaying in Greece, rather than studying or carrying out business.

Comment: Note that using "holiday" as a verb is British English. In American English you could say "All the concerts on the East Coast are happening while I am **on vacation in** Greece.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ideas;

The concerts I could have attended on the East Coast just happen to be scheduled while I'm planning to travel to Greece!

I will be traveling in Greece during the run of concert dates on the East Coast I was hoping to see.

Comment: Though the OP did indicate that they were open to new wordings, you should try to explain their nuances, and whether or not the original sentences were idiomatic/grammatical.